# ¿Como inserto un excel en una tabla de sql server sin insertar datos repetidos que tenga la tabla?

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net, azure-sql

alguien me podría ayudar con algo que me tiene trabada ya algunos días, lo que pasa es que, tengo que insertar los registros de un documento en excel en una tabla en sql server, pero tengo que verificar que los registros que inserto, no se repitan con los que ya tengo en la tabla, cree un Datareader para llenar una lista con los registros de la base, de la tabla donde insertare y despues paso el excel a una dataGridView, para recorrer este con dos foreach y obtener la comparación de los registros, pero ahora, supongamos que tengo 50 registros en la base y 3 en el excel y solo uno es repetido, me trae 149 registro, pero esta mal porque deberían de ser 49 para insertar, no se que hacer, si alguien pudiera orientarme.

```
string excelConectionConfig;
excelConectionConfig = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; ";
excelConectionConfig += "Data Source =" + openUrlExcel.FileName + "; ";
excelConectionConfig += "Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0; HDR=YES\" ";

OleDbConnection excelConnection = default(OleDbConnection);
excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConectionConfig);

OleDbCommand filterRows = default(OleDbCommand);
filterRows = new OleDbCommand("Select * From [Hoja1$]", excelConnection);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();

try
{
    OleDbDataAdapter adaptador = default(OleDbDataAdapter);
    adaptador = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    adaptador.SelectCommand = filterRows;
    adaptador.Fill(ds);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    try
    {
        SqlConnection conexion_destino = new SqlConnection();
        conexion_destino.ConnectionString = mi_conexion;

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT rfc FROM prefecto;", conexion_destino);
        conexion_destino.Open();

        //Ejecutar el comando SQL
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        List<string> resultado = new List<string>();
        resultado.Clear();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                resultado.Add(reader["rfc"].ToString());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");
        }
        reader.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------------");
        //Mostrar los datos de la tabla
        foreach (String rfc in resultado)
        {
            foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
            {
                foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                {   
                    if (row[0].ToString().Equals(rfc))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(row[0].ToString());
                        //aqui insertaria
                    }
                }
            }
        }
            conexion_destino.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Registros insertados con exito!");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error con la conexión de base de datos.");
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Formato de excel invalido");
}
```

Comment: Dices: *tengo 50 registros en la base y 3 en el excel y solo uno es repetido, me trae 149 registro, pero esta mal porque deberían de ser 49 para insertar* - No entiendo... ¿No deberían ser solamente 2 registros para insertar, no 49?

Comment: Compara fila por fila del excel contra la base de datos?

Comment: @LuisFernando es lo que hago, pero no puedo obtener los dos registros sin repetir, solo obtengo 149 registros repetidos.

Comment: Entonces se esta haciendo el proceso al contrario por asi decirlo?

Comment: entonces son 2 o 49 registros para insertar? La pregunta dice 49. Estoy confuso.

Comment: ¿Lograste solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1):

Tienes demasiados ciclos, que ni los puedo entender. En realidad solo necesitas un ciclo:

```
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{   
    string rfc = row[0].ToString();
    if (!resultado.Contains(rfc))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(rfc);
        //aqui insertaria
    }
}
```

Y, opcionalmente, si quieres mejor rendimiento, puedes cambiar:

```
List<string> resultado = new List<string>();
```

... a un `HashSet<string>`:

```
var resultado = new HashSet<string>();
```

Comment: muchas gracias, en realidad si necesito el primer for para acceder al table y de ahí a los row y gracias por el otro tip, soy nueva en c#. te calificaría, pero no puedo por ser nueva aqui

Comment: Hmm, no me había percatado de lo que dices. Pero en realidad, solo tienes una tabla, entonces no necesitas el ciclo adicional. Puedes combinar ambos en un ciclo. Acabo de corregir mi respuesta que en efecto tenía un pequeño defecto.